# How can I convert this TextBlock fade-in trigger to a Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, textblock

This XAML makes text fade in when it appears.

I would like to put this functionality into a Style.

However, but what do I put in for the "TargetName" since the style doesn't know which element is going to be using it?

How can I convert this fade-in effect to a style?

```
<TextBlock Name="Message" Text="This is a test.">
  <TextBlock.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="Message" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:3"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use TargetName. This works:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:3"/>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>  
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="Message" Text="This is a test.">
    </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```